# How do I get rid of a 0 (zero) in my formula result

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have dates in columns U,X,AA,AD,AG and AJ and Names in V,Y,AB,AE,AH and AK.  I have the following formula to select the latest updates as they are updated.  Columns U and V will be filled first and then columns X and Y are updated at a later date.  I need both the date and name column to be filled before the cells in another worksheet are updated.

This is the formula I am using, which is very long, but I can't work out how to make it shorter.  For the date I am swapping the columns for the date column (U,X,AA,AD,AG and AJ)in the second half of the formula

```
=CHOOSE(1+COUNT('Training Schedule'!U42,'Training Schedule'!V42,'Training Schedule'!X42,'Training Schedule'!Y42,'Training Schedule'!AA42,'Training Schedule'!AB42,'Training Schedule'!AD42,'Training Schedule'!AE42,'Training Schedule'!AG42,'Training Schedule'!AH42,'Training Schedule'!AJ42,'Training Schedule'!AK42),"",'Training Schedule'!V42,'Training Schedule'!Y42,'Training Schedule'!AB42,'Training Schedule'!AE42,'Training Schedule'!AH42,'Training Schedule'!AK42)
```

This formula works but if no entry is made in the name column a 0 (zero) is copied into the name column. How do I get it to show a blank cell?  If I add a name but no date nothing is copied across.  I have another formula to count the date and name formula to copy into another worksheet, but it is counting the 0 as if the cell if filled.  I have made so many versions of the file I'm working with and have mistakenly deleted my original which used to work with no 0 and I can't remember how I did it!

Comment: Would suggest to add an example worksheet.

Comment: how do I upload a worksheet?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have numbers in W42, Z42, AC42, AF42 & AI42 I would suggest the following alternate formula.

```
=IFERROR(IF(LEN(INDEX(V42:AK42, MATCH(1E+99, U42:AJ42))), INDEX(V42:AK42, MATCH(1E+99, U42:AJ42)), ""), "")
```

The above intermediate cells can contain text, but this method looks for the last number (aka date) in that range of cells so the intermediate cells cannot contain numbers or dates if the last date in U42, X42, AA42, AD42, AG42 & AJ42 is to be correctly determined.